# Why do my abbreviations not show up on the PDF?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm trying to get a list of abbreviations with the package acro. This is a minimal, reproducable Example:

```
\documentclass[13pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\begin{document}
\DeclareAcronym{uxo}{
 short = UXO ,
 long = Unexploded Ordenances , 
 tag = abbrev
}
\printacronyms[include=abbrev, name=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]   
\ac{uxo}

\end{document}
```

So printacronyms should print out all the acronyms I set with the tag abbrev, but all I get is the word "Abkürzungsverzeichnis". There are no Error-messages and I can use the abbreviations if I type `\ac{auv}` (like in the example). What is going on here?

Comment: Only the acronyms are displayed that are actually used. Did you compile twice so that they get picked up properly?

Comment: Yes I just did that. I put in \ac{auv} and hit the compile button twice. Still nothing. It shows the fully written acronym though. I also tried the same thing with \acs{auv}

Comment: @tomthecom Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: thanks for the tip, I did that @samcarter

Comment: @tomthecom Try with `\DeclareAcronym` in the preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}`

Comment: Yeah that did it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be avoided by placing `\DeclareAcronym` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[13pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{uxo}{
 short = UXO ,
 long = Unexploded Ordenances , 
 tag = abbrev
}

\begin{document}
    
\printacronyms[include=abbrev, name=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]   
\ac{uxo}

\end{document}
```